# Regex to remove youtube hyperlinks

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What I have

```
$string = "bla bla bla bla bla <a href='http://youtube.com/watch?=XXXXX'>my video</a> ble ble ble ble <a href='http://google.com'>google</a>";
```

What I want to get

```
$string = "bla bla bla bla bla ble ble ble ble <a href='http://google.com'>google</a>";
```

I want to remove only the youtube hyperlinks

Comment: I see two things wrong with this. Firstly, it's easy to use URL shorteners to get around this kind of thing. Secondly, assuming this content is coming from users, and you're allowing a tags, you're allowing any kind of HTML to be displayed. This allows for HTML injection and XSS attacks

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, removes all A tags that have the word youtube somwhere in them.

```
$string = "bla bla bla bla bla <a href='http://youtube.com/watch?=XXXXX'>my video</a> ble ble ble ble <a href='http://google.com'>google</a>";
echo preg_replace("#(<a.*youtube.*a>)#U","",$string);
```

You could expand this further to check for youtube.com/ or somthing more precise if you need to.

Comment: nice regular expression!

Answer (score 2):

This pattern works for the example you posted, let me know if you need it to be more specific.

```
$re = "/^(.*?)<a .*youtube.*>.*<\\/a>(.*?)$/Ui";
$str = "bla bla bla bla bla <a href='http://youtube.com/watch?=XXXXX'>my video</a> ble ble ble ble <a href='http://google.com'>google</a>"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
$string = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[1] . $matches[2] : ""; // Return a blank string for no match
```

Comment: This example would only remove a single youtube link and would be less efficient than using a preg_replace()

Comment: I agree with you here, preg_replace is the better solution for what was asked. I think I got carried away with an opportunity to play regex golf and missed the original point :S

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$string = "bla bla bla bla bla <a href='http://youtube.com/watch?=XXXXX'>my video</a> ble ble ble ble <a href='http://google.com'>google</a>";
$dom->loadHTML($string);

print_r("<pre>");
print_r($string);
print_r("</pre>");

print_r("<br />");

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
for ($i = $elements->length; --$i >= 0; ) {
    $href = $elements->item($i);
    if(strpos($href->getAttribute('href'), "youtube")) {
        $href->parentNode->removeChild($href);      
    }
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();

print_r("<pre>");
print_r($html);
print_r("</pre>");
die;
```

*Output:*

bla bla bla bla bla my video ble ble ble ble google

bla bla bla bla bla  ble ble ble ble google